# How To use arrays in if statement corectly in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have pretty basic question. sorry for that.
I'm trying to build result point system for test. but there is that problem everything is printing together. there is a code:

```js
    var g_Point = [8,9,10];
    var n_Point = [5,6,7];
    var b_Point = [1,2,3,4];

    var my_Points = 10;
    if(my_Points === g_Point){
        document.write('You Got Really Good Point');
    }else if(my_Points === n_Point){
        document.write('You Got Normal Points');
    }else if(my_Points === b_Point){
        document.write('You Got Really Bad Points');
    }
```

Comment: A number isn't equal to an array, which is what you're testing. It's not totally clear what you're trying to do, but if as I suspect it's to test which array the number (10 here) is *included* in, you want the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method

Comment: So i have a points from one to ten. 
i want to give definiton to my point as a text, if i got points from 8 to ten, i want to output specific text. that was the question.

Comment: and if i write like this n_Point[0,1,2]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing two values, you want to check if a value is included in an Array, then use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
var g_Point = [8, 9, 10];
var n_Point = [5, 6, 7];
var b_Point = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var my_Points = 10;
if (g_Point.includes(my_Points)) {
  document.write('You Got Really Good Point');
} else if (n_Point.includes(my_Points)) {
  document.write('You Got Normal Points');
} else if (b_Point.includes(my_Points)) {
  document.write('You Got Really Bad Points');
}
```